# find cumulative geometric average

Tags: excel, vba

I've got this code to calculate the cumulative geometric average of around 500 values (500 rows, 1 column) but I have tried to double check this and I am not getting the correct geometric average values.

```
Sub GeoR()

Dim No_Values As Integer
No_Values = 500

Dim Product() As Double
Dim Geo() As Double
Dim r() As Double

ReDim r(No_Values)
ReDim Geo(No_Values)
ReDim Product(No_Values)

For i = 1 To No_Values

r(i) = Range("returns").Cells(i, 1)
Product(i) = Application.Product(1 + r(i))
Geo(i) = (Product(i) ^ (1 / i)) - 1
Range("output").Cells(i, 1) = Geo(i)

Next i

End Sub
```

Could someone please help correct this code?

Comment: Sample data, along with expected results would help to understand what it is you are doing here.

Comment: There is not formula for `cumulative geometric average` in the procedure. You are calculating it individually with i

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use the worksheetfunction?

```
Function geo(rng As Range) As Double
    geo = Application.WorksheetFunction.GeoMean(rng)
End Function
```

example to call this

```
Sub geotest()
    Debug.Print geo(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A500"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice: no need for a VBA macro, then.